# Twitter Bootstrap - create preview

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question. I use Twitter Bootstrap to create theme.
I would like to create on my page something like preview with different size of views, but without change size browser window.

I want to create div with id "preview" and 4 buttons (xs,sm,md and lg) to change size this div to apply "mediaqueries" from TB.

Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the preview window with jQuery:

HTML

```
<div id="preview"> <a href="#" id="lg">Large</a>
 <a href="#" id="md">Medium</a>
 <a href="#" id="sm">Small</a>
 <a href="#" id="xs">Extra small</a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#preview {
    width: 1200px; // initial width
}
```

JS

```
$("#lg").on("click", function () {
    $("#preview").css("width", "1200px");
});
$("#md").on("click", function () {
    $("#preview").css("width", "992px");
});
$("#sm").on("click", function () {
    $("#preview").css("width", "768px");
});
$("#xs").on("click", function () {
    $("#preview").css("width", "767px");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6kLo0cxa/

Comment: It is not what I want. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cnyLggLo/1/ . "Visible" classes don't work on width.